# Need some advice- Should I use the CORDIC FFT function or write code for an FFT function myself?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx, fft, cordic

I'm currently working on designing a filter in VHDL for a project based on an FPGA. The filter would require FFT and I've heard about the CORDIC FFT function but never used it so I'm not sure how accurate it will be. So should I write VHDL code for an FFT function or use the CORDIC function? Also, does using the CORDIC FFT function require any permissions to be taken in case any work gets published?

Comment: If you want to *write* an FFT, then go ahead, use CORDIC in the twiddle section. If you want to *use* an FFT, then don't burn your whole project time writing one, use a pre-made one. You can do one, or the other, but not both.

Comment: If accuracy is your concern, you are better off with the IP, because accuracy-analysis is probably available. Doing this on your own can be tedious. What are your constraints? Time-to-market? Budget? FPGA resources? Throughput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the vendor specific generated block that is available to you. Then read the documentation for the block. For example [here](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/xfft/v9_0/pg109-xfft.pdf) is the documentation for the latest Xilinx FFT block. It will likely allow you to customize some parameters like input data size and block size.

Making your own FFT block could turn into a pretty advanced semester long undergraduate project.